# javascript - autocomplete hightlight text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, highlight

I have a search engine that display a list of results when you search something.
The problem is that when I slect one of those results, in the input will apear this text : `"<span style='font-weight:bold; color:"` and not the word wich is for search. 
For example if I want to search the word **"football"**, in the search input will appear this text :`"<span style='font-weight:bold; color:` and not the word **"football"**. 
Also in the url the `var t`  appears as a `<span> code` and not the word **"football"**

My code is this :

```
$("#search-field").data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
     var re = new RegExp("^" + this.term) ;
     var t = item.label.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:#000;'>" + 
              this.term + 
              "</span>");

    return $('<li></li>')
         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
         .append('<a href="http://beta.searchlotto.org.uk/yhs_search.php?q=' + t + '&cid=">' + t + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: How can you use ` in JavaScript?

Comment: I dont use those symbols in javascript, those symbols I have used for integrate this code in the grey box, so please read the code without them.